# Converstion string to date (format problem)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am struggling with conversion of a string variable to a date format.

The dates are currently in the format like 01JAN2008, 20JUN2019,...
I tried to convert these string to date with the following command:

```
select 
to_date(TRIM(start_dt, 'DDMONYYYY') as dt
from test
```

But that doesnt work. Can someone help me on that?

Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: Did you forget to close the parenthesis for TRIM()? Do it like this: `to_date(TRIM(start_dt), 'DDMONYYYY')`

Comment: *But that doesnt work*.... what exactly happens? An error? Incorrect results?

Comment: Sorry, yes I forgot to close the parenthesis.
But even after correcting that, I get a "null" value in my column. Is it linked to the SQL version I am using? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You missed one `)`:

```
SELECT to_date(TRIM('02JAN2020'), 'DDMONYYYY');
  to_date   
------------
 2020-01-02
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: ...*I tried to convert these string to date*... not the opposite.

Comment: @forpas thanks for the message. I got the question wrong :-)

Comment: Sorry, yes I forgot to close the parenthesis. But even after correcting that, I get a "null" value in my column. Is it linked to the SQL version I am using? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @arnaudd most likely one of your date strings are already null, e.g. `SELECT to_date(TRIM(NULL), 'DDMONYYYY');` gives a null resultset

Comment: @Jim Jones: Even when I test the statement you wrote here above, that gives me a null value... :-(
I wrote that sql statement via spark SQL. Do you think it is linked to that?Thanks a lot for your help! :-)

Comment: @arnaudd that's really odd. Which version of postgres are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone! I finally found my mistake. 
The statement working with spark sql is:

spark.sql("""
SELECT to_date(TRIM('02JAN2020'), 'ddMMMyyyy')
""")